# Webview onPageFinished never called

Tags: android, webview

I have came into a weird scenario of using Android WebView widget:

I have two activities, let's call them A and B. A has a button and a webview. Clicking the button in A will launch B. B has only a webview.

Here is the problem:
For certain urls, the "onPageFinished()" method of the WebViewClient (which is set on B) is never called, if Activity A is still on the stack. If I call finish() on A when launching B, the "onPageFinished()" will get called.

So it seems to me that the existence of webview in A has some effect on the other webview in B. Why is that? How can I solve this problem?

This problem only happens on my **OS 4.4** devices. For OS 5.x or OS 4.0, the code works perfectly.

Here is my source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ViewGroup browserContainer;
private WebView browser;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.background_material_dark));

    browserContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.webview_container);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.message_view);

    browserContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            browserContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    Button nextBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // uncomment below line will fix the problem
            // finish();
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        browser.onResume();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        browser.onPause();
    }
}}

public class WebviewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView browser;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.background_material_dark));

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.message_view);

    browser.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            showMessage();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // below url contains <video> component.
        String url = "http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5" ;
        browser.loadUrl(url);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        browser.onResume();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        browser.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Reveals the message.
 */
private void showMessage() {
    browser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}}
```

activity_main.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NEXT"/>
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/message_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_webview.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/message_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the HTML content retrieved by my webview in B activity has a video tag. Problem is that if this video tag does not have "preload" or "poster" attribute, then onPageFinished() method is never called. This bug is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63754). To fix the problem, modify the HTML content to add "preload=none" or "poster". For me, because I don't own the content, I have to download the content programmatically, add the "preload=none", and then feed the content to my webview. This is a hack, but it's the best I can think of now.